# Yarn to install all development packages

Tags: node.js, nestjs, yarn-v2, yarn-lock.json

I am developing a node.js (Nestjs) project & using Yarn instead of NPM for package management.

I have a simple question to ask, what is the command to force yarn to only install `devDependencies` ?  I checked the [document here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/), but can't figure out whether there is a option for it.

Answer (score 0):

To install the dev dependencies, you can run a command with "--dev" flag, following the example above:

```
yarn add {package name} --dev
```

Currently is not possible to install all dependencies separately.